# timezone independent formatting date-fns

Tags: javascript, date-fns

Currently i'm using [`date-fns`](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns) server-side to add meta data to certain records before saving to DB:

```
function getDateFormat(serverMillisTimestamp) {
  const current_unix = Math.round(serverMillisTimestamp / 1000)
  return {
    year: format(fromUnixTime(current_unix), 'yyyy').toString(),
    monthOfYear: format(fromUnixTime(current_unix), 'MMMM')
      .toString()
      .toLowerCase(),
    isoWeekOfYear: format(fromUnixTime(current_unix), 'II').toString(),
    dayOfMonth: format(fromUnixTime(current_unix), 'dd').toString(),
    isoDayOfWeek: format(fromUnixTime(current_unix), 'iiii')
        .toString()
        .toLowerCase()
  }
}
```

however on client-side when i use the same code to generate year, monthofYear, isoWeekOfYear, dayOfMonth and isoDayOfWeek so i can query the records from Database, there is a mismatch because the the format uses locale timezone to get these values.

How can i utilize the `date-fns` so the formatted values are timezone independent ?

Comment: I think you can't just ignore a time zone. You have use some common time zone both for your server and front-end app, UTC or something. Check docs here then: https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/Time-Zones.

Comment: that makes sense. how exactly would i format to UTC timezone

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
import {format} from "date-fns";
import {utcToZonedTime} from "date-fns-tz";

function getDateFormat(serverMillisTimestamp) {
  const utcTime = utcToZonedTime(serverMillisTimestamp, "UTC");
  return {
    year: format(utcTime, "yyyy").toString(),
    monthOfYear: format(utcTime, "MMMM").toString().toLowerCase(),
    isoWeekOfYear: format(utcTime, "II").toString(),
    dayOfMonth: format(utcTime, "dd").toString(),
    isoDayOfWeek: format(utcTime, "iiii").toString().toLowerCase(),
  };
}

const date = new Date();
console.log(getDateFormat(date.getTime()));
```